# Saving key-value in a local file - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, serialization, nsuserdefaults, icloud, key-value

I made an application which stores around 2,000 key-value integers.

I'm currently using NSUserDefaults but I can't save them all on iCloud as they are over 1 Mb in size.
I used to program Java application where i could store key-value numbers in List<> and Set<> and then serialising them.

My question is: can I store key-value integers in a way similar to Java Sets or in a different way instead of NSUserDefaults? So I'll sync the serialised file via iCloud.

Thanks for any help.

Simone.

Answer (score 1):

In place of `NSUserDefaults` you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Along with this you will need to implement `NSCoding` methods `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` unless the object is a supported collection class and there are no custom objects.

See [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)